# Postgresql Timestamp to to_char

Tags: postgresql

I need to showcase the date field from timestamp to char. For example, I am having the date value as `'2020-06-08 14:22:25.902'`. Now I need to show them as `'June 8, 2020'.` Is there any way to get the date value like this. can anyone please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use TO_CHAR:

```
select current_timestamp;
      current_timestamp       
------------------------------
 2020-06-15 10:41:46.82855+02
(1 row)

select to_char(current_timestamp, 'Month dd, YYYY');
      to_char       
--------------------
 June      15, 2020
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it:

```
postgres=# select regexp_replace(to_char(current_timestamp, 'Month DD, YYYY'), ' +', ' ');
┌────────────────┐
│ regexp_replace │
╞════════════════╡
│ June 15, 2020  │
└────────────────┘
(1 row)
```

More https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html

Comment: But you display the number of day in the week instead of the number of day in the month ?